# Is there anything wrong with the word “denigrate”?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, offensive-language

A few years ago there was a  controversy over the word *niggardly* — a perfectly innocent word that unfortunately sounds like a racial slur.

Given that controversy, is it safe to use *denigrate*, which is actually derived from the Latin *niger*?

Can whole families of words become tainted purely by association?

Comment: I'm no etymologist and probably not qualified to answer with any authority, but that won't stop me from offering my opinion. ;) I think the abandonment of perfectly acceptable words just because a few semi-literate individuals mistake them for racial slurs elevates ignorance to the level of a virtue.

Comment: I think your question is a bit on the argumentative side...are you really asking a question here, or just trying to confirm your opinion (which I happen to share, by the way)?

Comment: You're right, my question probably should be closed. :(  I don't think there would be an argument though... everyone would probably just agree.

Comment: I edited the question to make it less argumentative. @z7sg, feel free to edit further if you think it's necessary.

Comment: @JSBangs It's fine, thanks. But I may avoid this sort of highly subjective question in future because I have created a dilemma for myself choosing the 'right' answer.

Comment: @z7sg could you provide a context for your use of the word "denigrate"?

Comment: @Kelly C Hess: I'd upvote more if I could.  In fact, I _try_ to use "niggardly" (appropriately) just to set off the yahoos.  These are folks who would assume that because I'm a dogged curmudgeon that I have something to do with canines...if their stunted vocabulary extended that far.

Comment: @PSU: I like your style. :)

Comment: @PSU I'm quite happy to write _niggardly_ but using it in spoken English in front of a large number of people?  I'm not sure I would feel comfortable.

Comment: "I bet that even as I write, some adolescent boys, in the stairwell of some high school somewhere in America, are accusing each other of being niggardly, and sniggering at their own outrageous wit. I bet ... Wait a minute. 'Sniggering'? Oh, my God...."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  you've asked three questions.

Comment: This question is too open-ended and needs "because of _?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Nigger" is pronounced /ˈnigər/ and "denigrate" is pronounced /ˈdeniˌgrāt/. The /nigər/ part is completely missing and the accent isn't in a similar place.

For comparison, "niggardly" is pronounced /ˈnigərdlē/ which *does* have /nigər/ and the accent is in the same place. So no, *denigrate* doesn't sound enough like *nigger* to matter.

Comment: To which I'd add that "denigrate" is clearly Latinate to the ear. Making matters worse, the 'd' in "niggardly" is difficult to enunciate clearly. If you're unfamiliar with the word, you might well take offense at it. The context will usually not be flattering to the subject of the term. It's a bit sad that we've virtually lost a useful word due to widespread illiteracy.

Comment: @The Raven: I completely agree. The similarity between _niggardly_ and _niggerly_ are close enough for me to avoid using the word.

Comment: I’m sure this is the main reason.  Stress placement has a huge, huge effect on how similar-sounding we perceive words to be.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's certainly possible for whole classes of words to become taboo just because of sound-association. It's going on right now, for better or worse.

However, I doubt that *denigrate* will fall victim to this. In the first place, it doesn't sound very much like *nigger* or any derivative. Furthermore, you have to be fairly conversant in Latin to realize that the *-nigr-* part of *denigrate* has anything to do with "black", which prevents the association between the words from becoming strong or widespread enough to incur the taboo.

Comment: Thank God more ignorant people don't know Latin! Whew!

Answer (score 3):

I've never made that connection.  Is it racially offensive to say that someone is "blacklisted" or that he has done something to "blacken his name"?  Maybe go ahead and use it?

Comment: I have actually heard people disparage those phrases for exactly that reason. That's pretty far outside of the mainstream, though.

Comment: There was even a huge controversy about someone using the term "black hole".

Comment: @user744: If that actually happened, someone(s) need(s) to calm down.  Black is a color.  So are white, orange, pink, purple, and yellow.  Saying that someone has been "blacklisted" is closer to being reasonably racially offensive than "black hole".  The "black" in "black hole" isn't being negative about the blackness.  The blackness just has to do with it not giving off light!

Comment: More words falling down the "black" hole, guilty by association!

Answer (score 1):

- I don't think 'denigrate' is currently realized as possibly taboo because of the etymology or the sound.
- pointing out that connection, I'm almost inclined now to not use the word 'denigrate', but a close phonology is more likely to trigger taboo avoidance.
- I don't know about whole -families- of words, but certainly a single morpheme might be recognizable and so any word with it might share the taboo properties.
- How do you pronounce the seventh planet from the sun? It's at least humorous to every 10 year-old. People are changing the pronunciation because of it.
- There's a country in Africa whose pronunciation hasn't changed even though it is spelled very closely to the n-word.
- Associations are whatever people make and you can't control how other people make their associations. Whether there is a logical association that is hard to hear but intellectually discussed, or an unexpected phonetic change that makes a word sound like a taboo word, it doesn't matter. If some people don't like it then, well, they don't like it. Sometimes it is because of semi-literacy or lack of common culture, but it can also be pretty legitimate. Some things aren't taboo (or otherwise special) until it's about you.

Comment: Regarding the seventh planet, the new pronunciation isn't much better, meaning "urine colored".

Comment: Just stumbled upon this question... what's wrong with Uranus ? I don't get it.

Comment: @Alex: Nothing's wrong with my... ha ha! you almost got me, you clever ten-year-old!

Comment: @PSU: Which one is the 'new' pronunciation?  The 1892 *Webster's International* gives the "urine-colored" pronunciation. Presumably this was changed to your 'old' pronunciation to keep 10-year-olds from snickering.

Comment: Careful how you pronounce your name... Also, I always wonder about people named Gene, being reminded to wash up by everyone who greets them. The first name Hymen used to be popular, I knew one who was a doctor.